# Change a value in mutable list in Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, list, loops, kotlin

I got this mutablelist:

```
[Videos(id=4, yt_id=yRPUkDjwr1A, title=test4, likes=0, kat=pranks, ilike=false), Videos(id=3, yt_id=WkyUU9ZDUto, title=test3, likes=0, kat=pranks, ilike=false), Videos(id=2, yt_id=B_X9OQqtduE, title=test2, likes=0, kat=animals, ilike=false), Videos(id=1, yt_id=ywaKlGNiv80, title=test1, likes=0, kat=animals, ilike=false)]
```

How can I change `ilike` to `true` where `id` is `2`

This is what I've tried:

```
for (i in 0 until vids!!.size) {
    Log.d("lets", vids!!.get(i).title)
        
    if(vids!!.get(i).id == 2){
        vids!!.get(i).ilike = true
    }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can use `find` function to find the element with id = 2 and change its property:

```
vids?.find { it.id == 2 }?.iLike = true
```

Note: it is a good practice to use [question mark if the property is nullable](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) and you unsure whether it is null or not.

Comment: Same here as on other answer, I get "Val cannot be reassigned" :/

Comment: It seems `iLike` property marked as `val`. You need to make it `var` in your model: `Video(..., var iLike, ...) `

Comment: You are right :D I need to change it in the class where all the values of Videos are defined, thanks!

Answer (score 23):

If you expect few items (maybe 1 or 2?) to be affected, 
you can `filter` the list and then change `iLike` of the filtered items:

```
vids!!.filter { it.id == 2 }.forEach { it.iLike = true }
```

Answer (score 21):

Try this, I'm assuming your `Videos` structure is a data class defined somewhat like so.

```
data class Videos(
    val id: Int,
    val yt_id: String,
    val title: String,
    val likes: Int,
    val kat: String,
    val ilike: Boolean
)
```

for update the value

```kotlin
list.forEachIndexed { index, video ->
    video.takeIf { it.id == 2}?.let {
        list[index] = it.copy(ilike = true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I get the erroro "Val cannot be reassigned" on video.takeIf { it.id == 2 }?.ilike

Comment: So my assumption doesn't hold true then. You can't change the values in the `Videos` type. You have to completely replace the type. I'm updating the example above

Comment: Yeah sry Sergey was faster

Answer (score 12):

I had to change several properties and I had a need to hold the changed object. Therefore following approach worked better for me:

```
//First, find the position of the video in the list
val videoPosition= list.indexOfFirst {
   it.id == 2
}

//Now get your video by position and make changes
val updatedVideo = list[videoPosition].apply {
   //Make all changes you need here
   ilike = true

   //...
}

//Finally, replace updated video into your list. 
list[videoPosition] = updatedVideo
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `set` to replace the object if you don't want to use `predicates` or `iteration`

Eg.

```
val video = (...,read = true) //or however you are getting the current model
val updatedVideo = video
updatedVideo.read = true
vids[vids.indexOf(video)] = updatedVideo
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with Immutable lists, with `val` fields, and where you need to replace multiple items, you can do something like this:

```kotlin
val vids = vids.toMutableList()
vids.replaceAll {
  if (it.id == 2) {
    it.copy(iLike = true)
  } else { it }
}
```